What kind of math formula font is this?
I found an interesting math font in the book. I searched for a long time on my own, but did not find it. Therefore, this community is my last resort for finding an answer. Please help me find this font.



It could be beneficial to state which book this font was found within.

Not sure if this will help anyone. Современная иллюстрированная энциклопедия. Математика. Информатика. Росмэн 2007. [Modern illustrated encyclopedia. Mathematics. Computer science. Rosman 2007].

The second comment in this Russian math font might be helpful (David Carlisel comment)

A second example of comparable Russian math text font(s)

@Leucippus, yes, the fonts are very similar, but not identical. Thank you very much for your help!
